# @ControllerAdvice Annotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know this question has been asked, but the solutions proposed are not working for me. At the startup the bean restErrorHandler gets created and it's constructor is called. But when I throw a runtime exception in my controller it is not invoking this error handler. Instead it invokes the default handler:

```
Type=DEBUG,Category=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver,Thread="http-bio-8080"-exec-3,MDC=,Text=Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.egencia.auth.message.CreatePasswordPolicyResponse> com.egencia.service.controller.PasswordPolicyEndpoint.createPasswordPolicy(com.egencia.auth.message.CreatePasswordPolicyRequest,java.lang.String)]: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

The ControllerAdvice .

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(RestErrorHandler.class);




private Map<Class<? extends Exception>, HttpStatus> statuses;


public RestErrorHandler() {
    Map<Class<? extends Exception>, HttpStatus> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends Exception>, HttpStatus>();
    map.put(IllegalArgumentException.class, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    map.put(UnsupportedOperationException.class, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    map.put(BadSqlGrammarException.class, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    map.put(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    map.put(HttpMessageConversionException.class, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    map.put(HttpMediaTypeException.class, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    statuses = map;
}

/**
 * Map from exception type to Http status.
 * 
 * @param statuses
 *            the statuses to set
 */
public void setStatuses(Map<Class<? extends Exception>, HttpStatus> statuses) {
    this.statuses = statuses;
}


@ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
public  ResponseEntity<Object> processError(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    LOGGER.debug("inside rest error handler");



}
```

}

I have tried @EnableWebMVC annotation as well.

Comment: can u paste ur dispatcher-servlet too ???

Comment: as well try to put this line in ur dispatcher-servlet <context:annotation-config />

Comment: What happens if you remove `WebRequest request` from the handler? signature

Answer (score -1):

try annotate RestErrorHandler with a @Controller annotation